# CSS class override property behaviour

Tags: html, css

I tried to find answer to this but nothing straight forward, not on the StackOverflow or any of the tutorials.

So lets say I have external CSS file and class is defined there:

```
.someclass
{
    color: blue;
    margin: 10px
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 20px;
}
```

And I have pages where I want to override one or more properties of this class but keep everything else the same.
Pages include this external CSS file.
After that inside `<head>` tag I put this definition that overrides one property:

```
<style>
    .someclass
    {
        color: green;
    }
</style>
```

When everything is parsed what will be the final content of the `.someclass`?
This:

```
.someclass
{
    color: green;
}
```

or this:

```
.someclass
{
    color: green;
    margin: 10px
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 20px;
}
```

Comment: If you look in your inspector, you'll see both rules being applied. However, the `color` property will be overridden to green. `color: blue;` from the external sheet will be ignored.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the latter. Cascade resolution is on a per-property basis. If the `color` property exists somewhere with higher precedence (in this case, the internal stylesheet), then that property is cascaded to the more precedent one. The rest of the properties carry over because no more precedent declarations exist.

Interestingly, the [CSS2.1 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/cascade.html#cascade) seems to conflate "style rules" and style declarations, in section 6.4. This may be a source of confusion. The subsection 6.4.1 clarifies this by referring only to property declarations.

Comment: specificity !== order.

Comment: @torazaburo: lol yeah I totally shouldn't have used the word specificity there. Hang on.

Comment: Order is a component of specificity, albeit the weakest component.

Comment: Thank you all for your answers and links. It's clear to me now.

Answer (score 0):

When you have two style rules with identical selectors, the rule appearing later in the document wins.  So, if your `<link>` tag is before your `<style>` tag, the property from the rule in the `<style>` tag will be applied.

Demo:

```css
p {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: green;
}
p {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<p>I am blue, not green.  I am also both bold and sans-serif!</p>
```

In fact, the selectors needn't be identical for this to apply.  If they have the same [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity), the rule defined later wins.  For example, if an element has two classes defined:

```css
.a {
  width: 100px;
  padding: 8px;
  color: white;
  background-color: red;
}
.b {
  height: 75px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="a b">I am green!</div>
```

Or, for an element with multiple ancestor elements and rules that use the [descendant combinator ()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Descendant_selectors):

```css
html span {
  font-style: italic;
  color: orange;
}
body span {
  text-decoration: underline;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: navy;
}
```

```html
<span>I'm navy!</span>
```

Or, for elements that have multiple pseudo-classes applied.  I can see this one tripping someone up:

```css
a:hover {
  text-decoration: overline;
  color: orange;
}
a:link, a:visited {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<a href="#orange">I'm a link that doesn't change color when hovered</a>
```

Comment: Added a demo for the downvoter as proof.  Do you think my statement is incorrect?

Answer (score 0):

This is not necesary true Gilly3... it will depended on the rule specificity and it will also depend whether you are using the important flag or not... you definitely will inherit from the predecessor but you won't necessary overwrite it...

**here an example see the results:** 
http://jsfiddle.net/leojavier/xg4fffms/1/

```
<p class="text">Testing</p>
<p class="textb">Testing</p>
<p class="forceYellow textb">Testing</p>
```

CSS

```
body{
    background:#CCC;
}
body p.text {
    color:red;
}
.textb {
    color:purple;
}

p{
    color: blue;
}

.forceYellow {
    color:yellow !important;
}
```

Comment: The key phrase in my answer is **with identical selectors**.  In fact, the selectors don't even need to be identical, they just need to have the same specificity.  Eg, for this element: `<div class="foo bar"></div>`, the following rules have the same specificity: `.foo { }` `.bar { }`.  If those rules have conflicting properties, the property from the rule defined later in the document will be applied.